# App crashing after iOS 11.2.6 update

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

The code for my CLLocationManagerDelegate was working fine before the last iOS update, however now it is crashing with the error `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didUpdateLocations:'`

This is the code for my delegate (note: `start()` is called from my ViewController):

```
class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func start() {
        locationManager.delegate = self

        if locationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization)) {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else {
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
    }

    func startLocationUpdates() {
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // snip
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // snip
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're initializing this class, setting delegates, etc., but this is the `UserLocation` class that I use. Compare it to yours.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

var userLocation: UserLocation?

class UserLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var launchLocationSet = false

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupLocationManager()
    }

    public var currentLocation: CLLocation!

    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    private func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation!
        if !launchLocationSet {

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateLocation"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            launchLocationSet = true

        }
    }

    func currentLatitude() -> CLLocationDegrees {
        return currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    }

    func currentLongitude() -> CLLocationDegrees {
        return currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked it on the latest 11.2.6?

Comment: I added the code where I initialize the class and setup the delegate